# QuickFIXJ MessageCracker different behaviour in NetBeans and JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, quickfixj

I have a strange issue. I'm using MessageCracker in my quickfixj client application and do have a custom message in my dictionary that the server side requires to have.

Now the problem is that the custom message is cracked properly when running from NetBeans however it is not cracked at all when I build and run it from a JAR(with dependencies) on the same machine.

Since I am quite new to programming I have no idea what might cause this difference in behaviour.
I have looked around and tried:

1. deleting NB caches
2. deleting the projects cache
3. deleting the project, creating a new one and copying only the source files there
4. a couple different quickfixj libraries

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you did not install the rebuilt QuickFIX/J library (if you rebuilt it with the new data dicationary), or you don't have the same configuration file installed referencing the changed data dictionary?

Comment: @TT. Thanks for your answer. Actually I only use the quickfix code generator that creates new references from my modified data dictionary each time I run 'clean and build'. There are .properties files for QuickFIX that point to the correct data dictionary.
I'm probably missing something very basic here due to being quite new to the field.

Comment: So IIUYC, you do rebuild the QuickFIX/J library from a modified dictionay. Make sure that in your installation, you have this rebuilt library along with the changed data dictionary, with a reference to this changed data dictionary in your configuration file (file name is `fixengine.cfg`, element is `DataDictionary`; see [QuickFIX/J configuration](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.1//usage/configuration.html)).